# Cauchy RV X has pdf f(x)=$c/1+x^2, x>0$ and $0, x\le0$

Tags: probability

Cauchy RV X has pdf f(x)=$c/1+x^2, x>0$ and $0$ otherwise

a) Find c
$\int_0^\infty c/1+x^2$=arctan($\infty$)-arctan(0)=$\pi/2$

b) Compute E(1/$\sqrt{1+X^2}$)
$\int_0^\infty (1/\sqrt{1+(\pi/2)/(1+x^2)})*(\pi/2)(1/1+x^2)$

c) Find the pdf of $\sqrt{|X|}$
$P(Y\le y)=P(\sqrt{|X|} \le y)=P(|X|\le y^2)=\int_0^{y^2}(\frac{\pi}2)\frac1{1+x^2}$

Can someone help me check my work? Pretty sure this is all wrong except a cause the numbers are super funky

Comment: What is *"$x>$ and  $0, x\le0$"* supposed to mean? Note that the support of [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution) is $(-\infty,+\infty)$.

Comment: Sorry corrected it

Comment: But then it's not a Cauchy distribution. It's sometimes called half-Cauchy distribution. Just to clarify the terminology.

Comment: Sorry that's what's written in the problem. I don't disagree with you but that's how it's stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a)

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac c{1+x^2}\mathrm dx=c\frac{\pi}{2}$$

But the integral must equal $1$ since you integrate a continuous probability distribution on its support. So $c=\dfrac{2}{\pi}$.

b)

$$E(g(X))=\frac2\pi\int_0^{\infty}\frac{g(x)}{1+x^2}\mathrm dx$$

So

$$E\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+X^2}}\right)=\frac2\pi\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{3/2}}\mathrm dx$$

And note that a primitive of $\dfrac{1}{(1+x^2)^{3/2}}$ is $\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$.

c)

First note that $X\ge0$ so $\sqrt{|X|}=\sqrt{X}$. Then the usual [LOTUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician). Let $Y=\sqrt{X}$, for any measurable function $g$,

$$E(g(Y))=E(g(\sqrt{X}))=\int_0^{\infty} g(\sqrt{x}) f_X(x)\mathrm dx$$

Now with a change of variable $x=y^2$

$$E(g(Y))=\int_0^{\infty} g(y) f_X(y^2)\cdot 2y\mathrm dy$$

So $f_Y(y)=2yf_X(y^2)$.

Comment: Did you get infinity for b? That's what I got

Comment: @user8714896 No. The given primitive has limit $1$ as $x\to\infty$ and $0$ for $x\to0$, so the expected value is $\dfrac2\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

For part $b$, you should compute

$$\frac{\pi}2\int_0^\infty \frac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\frac{1}{1+x^2}\, dx=\frac{\pi}2\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^\frac32}\, dx$$

For part $c$, seems fine if $y> 0$. Just differentiate with respect to $y$.

Comment: I got infinity for b does that seem right? What do you mean differentiate with respect to y? Isn't it on x then set the var to y

Comment: I got $(\pi/2) \frac{2y}{y^4 + 1}$ for c does that seem right?